# Handlebars JS replacing portion of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a helper called replace. I know there is one already, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to replace just a portion of a string and return the rest

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{#replace "&" title}}and{{else}}{{/replace}}
</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{body}}
  </div>
</div>

{ 
  title: "The Amazing Red & Tshirt", 
  body: "This is a short story about the red t-shirt"
}
```

Helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('replace', function( find, replace, options) {
    var string = options.fn(this);
    return string.replace( find, replace );
});
```

All I seem to be able to do is replace the entire string, rather than a small segment of the string. in this instance replacing the & symbol with the word and.

I'm sure it's easy, but I can't seem to do anything other than replacing the entire block with the word and.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

What is `var string = options.fn(this);` reffering to is what's inside the helper, like between the two constructs of brackets:

```
{{#helperName}}this{{/helperName}}
```

So what is your helper call doing at the moment is:

1. trying to replace `find = '&'` inside the `this = 'and'`
2. with your `title = 'The Amazing Red & Tshirt'`.

What you should do is calling your helper this way:

```
{{#replace "&amp;" "and"}}{{title}}{{/replace}}
```

Do notice the **whole entity** passed as an argument instead of the single **&** character.